# Performing action of "Tab" key with "Enter" click, inside a Bootstrap Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div class = "row"></div>` provided by Bootstrap, this row have multiple elements one select, two buttons and multiple inputs.

```
<div class="row" id="productlist">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Producto</label><br/>
      <select class="select2_single form-control tg" id="product" name="product" size="4">
          <option>Seleccionar Producto</option>
          //PHP 
      </select>
      <br/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Cantidad (Kilogramos)</label><br/>
      <input class="tg" type="text" placeholder="Cantidad" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br/>
      <label>Precio</label><br/>
      <input class="tg" type="text" placeholder="Precio" id="price" name="price"><br/>
      <label>Número de Rollos</label><br/>
      <input class="tg" type="text" placeholder="Número de Rollos" id="numrolls" name="numrolls"><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Observaciones</label><br/>
      <input class="tg" type="text" placeholder="Observaciones" id="remarks" name="remarks"><br/>
      <label>Número de Paquetes</label><br/>
      <input class="tg" type="text" placeholder="Número de Paquetes" id="numpackages" name="numpackages"><br/><br/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success fixedbutton" id="add">Agregar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to perform the same action that throws the "Tab Key" when the user use "Enter" so I made this jquery, probably the problem is that all the div is multiple columns and not just one.

```
 $('.tg').bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 13) {
    var nextItem = $(this).next('.tg');

    if( nextItem.size() === 0 ) {
      nextItem = $('.tg').eq(0);
    }
    nextItem.focus();
  }
});
```

Also, I show a alert when the inputs are empty and the user click in the add button (id = "add")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keypress event, You can use `$($('.tg')[$('.tg').index(this)+1]);` to get next item having class `tg`.

This will not cover buttons . To cover buttons you will have to add class `tg` to buttons. Now if focus is on button then "click" event will be triggered if you will press "Enter" key. If you don't want to trigger click event on "Enter" key then you can use following code snippet.

```
$('.tg').bind('keypress', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 13) {
    var nextItem = $($('.tg')[$('.tg').index(this)+1]);
    if( nextItem.size() === 0 ) {
      nextItem = $('.tg').eq(0);
    }

    if($(this).attr('type') =='button'){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    nextItem.focus();
  }
});
```